# USE statement before CREATE VIEW

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The truth: I am not good at SQL, and after some research I am unable to figure this out. I am reading a chapter on utilizing views and am unable to get this query to work :

```
USE [jm0235242]
CREATE VIEW InvoiceBasic 
AS
SELECT VendorName, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceTotal
FROM Vendors JOIN Invoices ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
```

It has issues with my USE statement:

> *'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch".*

My question is, how am I supposed to specify which database it is supposed to look at if I cannot use my USE statement. Thanks for any help, and happy thanksgiving!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You  need to make sure that the `CREATE VIEW` is the first statement in a SQL batch - as the error clearly explains. So use this:

```
USE [jm0235242]
GO      --  put that "GO" separator here! 

CREATE VIEW InvoiceBasic 
AS
SELECT VendorName, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceTotal
FROM Vendors JOIN Invoices ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
```

When you run this in SQL Server Management Studio, the `GO` keyword ends a batch and executes it - and the `CREATE VIEW` is now the first statement in the second batch, and it's happy and works, too

**Update:** the question **why** exactly the `CREATE VIEW` (and also `ALTER VIEW`, for that matter) must be the first statement of a batch eludes me - I've never heard any compelling explanation for this. Maybe a Microsoftie or someone close to the team knows this and can explain for us all? :-)

Comment: Possibly related, but what effect does `;` have on queries structured like this in MS SQL? General curiosity.

Comment: @TheCapn: the semicolon just terminates a statement - but not a batch. You can still have multiple statements - all semicolon-terminated - within a single batch

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out and saw you answered my question when I refreshed!

Answer (score 1):

Needed a "GO".....answered my own question! Can anybody tell me why I need this though, because I would like to comprehend why I need it.